# Let $[a, b]\subset\Bbb{R}$ and let $c \in[a,b]$. Prove that there exists a sequence of rational numbers $(r_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n=c$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I do have a hint for this question, which says: For each $n\in\Bbb{N}$, choose a rational number in the interval $(c-\frac{1}{n}, c+\frac{1}{n})\cap[a,b]$.

This question also has another part which I can't seem to figure out either.

Let $[a,b]$ be an interval in $\Bbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function which is continuous on $[a,b]$. Prove that if $f(x)=0$ for every rational number $x$ in $[a,b]$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x ∈ [a,b]$.

For the second one, I'm assuming that I'm basically proving that if $f(x)=0$ for every rational number, then $f(x)=0$ for every irrational number as well. I just don't know where to start with either of these.

Comment: As posed, your question makes no use of $a$ and $b$. Are you sure you have it right?

Comment: I do have that $a<b$. I couldn't fit it in the title. That's it though.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to tell us that each $r_n$ must also be in $[a,b]$? Otherwise $a$ and $b$ play no role.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm just giving you the whole problem. All it says is to prove that there exists a sequence of rational numbers $(r_n)_n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that the limit as that sequence approaches infinity equals c.

Comment: @TonyK, the sequence would have to eventually be in $[a,b]$, but I don't think it needs to have each $r_n$ in there. (Of course you can just take my sequence and chop off the start a bit to get yours, so it's all the same)

Comment: @mdave16 yeah, the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})$ has a limit 1 which is in [0,10].

Comment: Yeah. I see what you're saying, though I'm unsure to how to prove it.

Comment: Ok, all good observations here and in the answers. I just want to point out in the title, you probably meant $[a,\ b] \subset \mathbb R$. Just a small technical point, but it's important to keep these in mind as the small points are what can lead to a big misunderstanding. As for the second problem you described, have you considered giving a proof by contradiction?

Comment: I am quite sure you have the question wrong (or the question setter made a mistake). The hint makes it clear that the $r_n$ are expected to lie in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId you're right. I was running out of room and put the wrong symbol. My fault.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId Also, I haven't thought about a contradiction, though I'm unsure how I would go about it. Assume that there every rational $x\in[a,b]$ has $f(x)=0$ and then assume, towards contradiction, that not every $x\in[a,b]$ has $f(x)=0$? In other words, there exists an irrational number y in $[a,b]$ such that $f(y)=0$?

Comment: @user21 Almost there.  By assumption toward contradiction, $\exists y \in [a,\ b] : y \not \in \mathbb Q$ **and**  $f(y) \neq 0$. This leads to a contradiction almost immediately because of the set of premises we started out with for this part of the problem. To reach a contradiction we must contradict at least one of the premises. To list them quickly they are: 1. $f$ is defined and continuous on $[a.\ b]$. 2.$\ \forall x \in \mathbb Q \cap [a,\ b], f(x) = 0$. I think this is a good starting point.

Comment: Additional hint: Once you correctly arrive at a contradiction, you will see exactly why the authors organized the whole problem the way they did.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId Okay, I'm just not seeing the contradiction. The function can still be continuous even if there exist an irrational number y such that $f(y)\neq0$ right? And we aren't contradicting the second assumption since $y\notin\Bbb{Q}$, right? Am I missing something? I feel like it's really obvious and i'm just not seeing it...

Comment: I was going to give a broad sketch of the proof, but I couldn't stand skimming over the details. I will add an answer below now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

1) Every number has a decimal expansion, so can be approximated, this is a rational number and it tends to anything in the reals (I've overly simplified what all this means, but you can make it rigourous.

Every real number is rational or irrational. If rational, sure we can use $c + \frac{1}{n}$ like you say, but we could also choose the sequence $c,c,c,c,c,\dots$, which converges a lot more obviously to $c$ and is a rational sequence.

If it's irrational, then I want to construct a rational sequence which tends to it. Well, a number $x$ has a decimal expansion (check, this has to be well defined and so on). Say $x = x_n \dots x_3x_2x_1x_0.x_{-1}x_{-2}x_{-3}x_{-4}\dots$. What sort of rational sequence can I construct knowing this to get $x$? I have very literally constructed a sequence of rationals that will tend to any irrational number, I don't know how to make this more obvious without just giving you the answer.

2) Let's use the help of our great friends/enemies $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$, the iconic duo of the analysis world. Things are continous, but between every two rational people in analysis world, there is one who is irrational. And between every two irrational people, there is a rational person. (Prove it)

Let's say for contradiction sake that $f(x) \neq 0$ for some real number $x$.
Now we have a dichotomy (forced choice) that means $x$ is rational or irrational. If $x$ is rational, well $f(x)=0$ by construction.

So $x$ is irrational. But, $f$ is continuous, and there is $x_+,x_-$ above and below $x$ that are rational and arbitrarily close to it, and the value on $x_+,x_-$ are $0$. hmmm continuous, hmmm 0..., hmmm not going to do assignment questions until I see you've tried a lot, but will still give hints spelling out the answer...

Name a continuous function that has a value at $1$ but in any epsilon neighbourhood of it, it's $0$. I double dare you to find such a function.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've been busy with other stuff. Could we not just say that for any $c\in[a,b]$, we can create a sequence, $(r_n)=c+\frac{1}{n}$? Then the limit of that sequence will be c?

Comment: We've learned that between every two rational numbers is an irrational number and vice versa i'm pretty sure. How does that show that the limit at the irrational numbers are different than the rational though?

Comment: I understand what you're doing with both of them. I just can't think of a sequence that we can construct to obtain the irrational x-value for the first one. For the first one, I'm not seeing the contradiction. I'm understanding exactly what you're doing, but I'm missing the contradiction. I feel like it's very obvious, but I'm not seeing it. I understand exactly what's going on, I just can't finish it out I guess.

Comment: try drawing the second one. for the first one, I'm strongly hinting at just one solution, there are actually infinitely many solutions, I can think of 2 off the top of my head, but i'm giving you the most obvious one.

Comment: Okay. I see. For the second one, the function couldn't be continuous if the f(x) value was jumping from 0 to another value when the x values are infinitely close to each other. That makes sense. Probably not the most mathematical way of saying it, but it makes sense to me. For the first one, the sequence you're constructing is just the decimal expansion of the irrational number? If that's not correct, no worries. I can sense the frustration from you and I understand it. I'm not doing a good job of understanding the question. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: YESYY!Y!Y!Y!Y!YY!THAT IS WHAT I MEANNN, NOW YOU JUST HAVE TO USE EPSILON DELTA TO DO THIS RIGOUROUSLY, in all fairness, i'm not a great explainer, and this isn't the best medium for live teaching. I'll re-write my answers in a bit so they are less directed for your help and just nice answers. Also don't forget to vote up my ans and accept it and blah blah blah, you know.

Comment: Hahaha thanks so much. I really appreciate it. I'm a slow learner.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a good example of a question which "builds" up through the various concepts it makes use of.

The author(s) intend for the reader to come up with a good understanding of the "connectedness" of the real line and how this eventually translates into the "connectedness" of continuous functions defined on such domains.

The first part is really a major hint for the main problem, which is the second part.

So, let's review the first part very quickly. To re-iterate

1. $a < b$
2. $[a,\ b] \subset \mathbb R$
3. $c \in [a,\ b]$ is an indeterminate but fixed real number in that domain.

Although, we *can* technically pick the sequence $\{c,\ c,\ c, \cdots\}$ (if $c$ is rational), I think it's worthwhile pointing out that we can satisfy an even stronger condition here. Namely, that we can find a monotone increasing or monotone decreasing sequence which is contained **entirely** in $[a,\ b]$. Other conditions can also be satisfied.

That is where the example they gave comes handy. Though it isn't necessary, it's their way of encouraging you to pick such a sequence. Note, however, that expression for obtaining a sequence may not be helpful for certain combinations of $a, b$ and $c$. This can be easily remedied by using a sequence of rational numbers from intervals of the form $(c - n^{-k},\ c + n^{-k})$ for large enough $k.$

If I remember correctly, this is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$, which implies that it is convergent.

Now, the second part.

We will use a proof by contradiction. Our premise is:

1. $f$ is defined and continuous on $[a,\ b],$ and
2. $\forall x \in \mathbb Q \cap [a,\ b], f(x) = 0$.

Our contradiction will come from assuming the negation of the desired conclusion. So, the assumption toward contradiction is

$$\exists x_1 \in [a,\ b] : x_1 \not \in \mathbb Q \land f(x_1) \neq 0.$$
We need only prove this with the existence of exactly **one** such $x_1$.

There are other stronger claims to be made here, for example, there are finitely many ($> 1$) such irrational numbers in that interval, there are countably infinitely many such numbers, etc. But all of those cases are either trivial extensions of the case with a single point, or imply that the contradiction follows by definition.

For the case with a single point, notice we can get arbitrarily close to $x_1$ where as the difference $|f(x) - f(x_1)|$ does *not* get arbitrarily small for $x \in [a,\ b]$. This is one of the definitions of continuity.

Therefore, this contradicts the requirement that $f$ be continuous on the given domain. More precisely, take $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [a,\ b]-\{x_1\}$, and $f(x_1) = d \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$. I'm going to assume boundary cases have been well accounted for. Q.E.D.

Interestingly enough, if we had assumed that there was more than one irrational number for which $f(x) \neq 0$, the contradiction would make more evident the need of the second of the original set of premises we listed.

Finally, if I have missed something, many apologies. Please feel free to point it out or ask further questions.

Comment: one of the important features of part 1 was the sequence is all rational, despite that, this is a really good answer, I'll try and make mine more ordered and nice looking at somepoint tomo +1

Comment: @mdave16 Thank you. Yes, you're right, the sequence does have to be all rational, I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer works
for any dense set,
not just the rationals:

[Suppose $f(x)$is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=x$, when $x$ is irrational in $[0,1]$. Show that $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198562/suppose-fxis-a-continuous-function-on-0-1-such-that-fx-x-when-x-i/2198595#2198595)

Just replace
"$f(x) = x$"
with
"$f(x) = 0$".

Comment: you only answered the second part, the missed out the (very easy) first part

Comment: I miss out on a lot.

Comment: We haven't learned anything about dense sets, so I'm not sure what a lot of this means lol

Comment: A set A is dense in a set B if, for any point x in B and distance d there is a point in A that is within d of x. For example, the irrationals, the rationals, and the dyadic rationals are all dense in any interval of the reals.

Another way to state the definition is that every point in B is the limit of a sequence of points in A.

Comment: @martycohen For the second definition you have, would it be more precise to say it as such: For every point in B there exists a sequence of points, all contained in A, such that the sequence converges to the given point in B?

Comment: I think the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint, let $r_n$ be a rational number in $(r-\frac1n,r+\frac1n)\cap[a,b]$. Then in particular, $|r_n-r|<\frac1n\to0$. Now follow marty cohen's answer for the second part.